# Why am I getting this error on heroku but not in development in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm getting this error in my heroku logs:

[image: Heroku Error]

Here's the create method in my pins_controller

```
def create
code = params[:pin][:code]
@classroom = Classroom.where('code LIKE ?', code).first
unless @classroom
  flash[:error] = "Classroom code incorrect"
  render :new
else
  params[:pin][:classroom_id] = @classroom.id
end


  @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
  @pin.save
  params[:pin][:emotion_ids].each do |emotion_id| 
    @emotion = Emotion.find(emotion_id)
    @pin.emotions << @emotion
  end

  respond_with(@pin)
  authorize @pin

 end
```

I recently created a new instance of my app on a staging url and a product url (pointing to my domain) I ran rake db:migrate so that should be working and most of the other features on the site are fine.

Why would this work locally but not in heroku?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any emotions in the database?

Comment: The parameters log, 2 lines above the highlighted line in the log, there is no parameter named `emotion_ids` inside `pin` parameter. Hence the error. As to why it works in development, you need to show us logs from development.

Comment: aha! no i don't have emotions in the DB yet. That's got to be the problem.

Comment: @Deekor simple solution! That was it. Thank you! if you add your answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your database has some emotions in it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be you haven't seeded your database yet since you only ran a migration. If there were emotion objects in your database in your development environment they won't be in your heroku production environment. Maybe create a seed file, add some emotions to it, and see if the error still exists. It doesn't seem like a problem on heroku just seems like a lack of an object existing when you call each on it.

Comment: Had to give the answer to Deekor because he was actually the first to give me the answer.